# How to clear notification in didreceiveremoteNotification method when app running in background?

Tags: ios

I need to clear the notification in notification center , when i click notification in notification center or badge when app in background. I can able to get log in didreceiveremoteNotification . But not clearing the notification in notification center.

Answer (score 0):

you could try these two lines which i am always using when receiving a notification

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

`setApplicationIconBadgeNumber` is a multipurpose property to set the badge number and also clear the notifications

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to clear the badge of the push notification.

If so, use this code in

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

**applicationDidBecomeActive**